# why the margin-top is larger than its setted under IE8?

Tags: html, css

the link:  http://xanlz.com/test/test.html

the css:

```
    .hot-version, .week-down, .total-down, .tag {
        border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
        height: 286px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 1px;
}
```

[image] [image]

the red part margin-top is larger in IE8 and ok under firefox,IE7. why? how to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Use css hacks:
IE7 and below can parse `*property: value`

```
.hot-version, .week-down, .total-down, .tag {
        border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
        height: 286px;
        margin-top: 10px; //for IE8
        *margin-top: //another value for IE7;
        padding: 1px;
}
```

**EDIT:**
These two links provide more hacks for IE6/7/8:
http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/ 
http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#in_css